# Creativity as a process

Tags: translation

I'm struggling with finding an exact match for Russian word "Творчество" which according to Wikipedia is synonymous to the word "Creativity" in English. "Творчество" is defined an activity that yields something completely new, that never existed before; the result of this process is something which is valuable not only for creator but for the others too. That result also can't be inferred by simply applying some known rules to the known input data. Or to quote Niels Bohr - "This theory is crazy, but not crazy enough to be true" - meaning that logical inference is not equivalent to the notion of "Творчество".

While I'm not a native speaker I still doubt that "Творчество" and "Creativity" are completely the same, so my question is whether I'm wrong and "Creativity" indeed conveys the exact meaning of the word "Творчество".

Comment: [_Invention_](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/invention?s=t), [_inventiveness_](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inventiveness), or [_ingenuity_](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ingenuity?s=t) might be in the right realm.

Comment: You're extremely unlikely to come up with an exact match, and unlikely to come up with a better one.

Comment: "discovery" comes to mind for me...especially as the word is used in a more figurative way.  "a voyage of discovery" - .. it fits the part of your request "that yields something completely new, that never existed before; the result of this process is something which is valuable not only for creator but for the others too."

Comment: discovery works for knowledge though, not for something like a symphony. (one might discover new harmonic methods, that you applied in the symphony)

Comment: I add innovation, for introducing something fresh and new.

Comment: Your Russian word sounds a little more exclusive than creativity, but creativity is I think as close as you'll get.  Innovation implies application of invention to commerce.  Invention may involve great creativity or simply be a moderate advance.  Music, art, literature, sometimes science, have creative breakthroughs.

Comment: I wonder if you're looking for "serendipity" ??   Could you please ***give some example sentences*** of the exact sense you mean Alex?  (Your quote from Bohr is totally confusing by the way - I have no clue what you mean there.)